# How to clear the client-side .Net SSL session cache

Tags: .net, caching, session, ssl

I am writing a little test tool, which uses HttpWebRequest to load test a server. I want for
each time I try to call HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() for it establish a fresh SSL session instead of using the one in the cache. Note: I am supplying a client certificate, and using Mutual Authentication for the SSL Session.

Is there a way to clear the SSL Session cache referred to in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.clientcertificates.aspx  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the HttpRequestCacheLevel Enumeration value NoCacheNoStore

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cache.httprequestcachelevel.aspx

You can then overwrite the HttpRequestCachePolicy

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.cachepolicy.aspx

Comment: But this is HTTP-level caching, isn’t it? The OP requested clearing the _SSL session_ cache (which keeps temporary per-session keys, speeding the initial SSL handshake up), AFAICT.

Answer (score 6):

The ServicePoint class has an internal method called [`ReleaseAllConnectionGroups`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/ServicePoint.cs,16691643dcf47f83) that sets `KeepAlive = false` on all the connections then releases them. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29931394) includes all the reflection needed, but setting `KeepAlive = false` on every HttpWebRequest will keep the client-side .Net SSL session cache clear.

[`SslEmptyCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380388.aspx) may be required to clear [caching of SSL-SessionID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419434/how-renegociate-ssl-connection-every-time-different-ssl-sessionid-windows-c) and/or tickets done by SCHANNEL at the native-code level.

Comment: Setting KeepAlive = false worked great.  Tried setting HttpRequestCachePolicy first, but it had no effect.

Comment: Setting KeepAlive = false did nothing for me.