# How to use a self-signed SSL certificate without ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

I have an `HttpClient` which uses a self-signed SSL certificate which is saved on the client computer as a `.cer` file. To validate the certificate, I use ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback in the following way (not my actual code, just the essence):

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, errors) =>
{
    if (errors == SslPolicyErrors.None) return true;
    if (cert.Subject == "CN=CertificateCommonName")
        return CertificatesMatch(cert, GetSavedCertificateFromFile());
    else
        return false;
};
```

However, I noticed that this function only gets called once for any certificate per process (more exactly per AppDomain, probably), which means that once a certificate has been validated, it is stored somewhere in a "valid certificates cache". Is there a way I can simply add my saved certificate to that cache?

I wish I could simply use an `HttpClientHandler` with my `HttpClient` and add the certificate to the `ClientCertificates` property, however I am targeting .NET Framework 4.5, and that feature is only available from .NET Framework 4.7.1, so that is not an option.

Comment: Does this answer help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845781/how-to-clear-any-ssl-certificate-data

Comment: @GuyatMercator Doesn't look like it. The "Certificate" and "ClientCertificate" properties on ServicePoint are ReadOnly. I wouldn't dare start using reflection to set the underlying private fields.

Comment: SSL is obsolete but the name is used with TLS.  When a request is made TLS is automatically performs when the URI is HTTPS before the request is send.  With Net before 4.7.1 the TLS Authentication was only performed in Net.  Since Net 4.7.1 the default is to use the Operating System for TLS and Net can be used by changing configuration options.  Older version of Net do not support all the TLS encryption modes so your Framework 4.5 may not work with TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3 (SSL, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 are now obsolete).  In your case everything is working and certificae only needs to be validated once.

Comment: I see. Indeed, the security protocol I'm using is TLS 1.1 but I'm using SSL as a general term. Are you saying that older versions of .NET are less flexible with regards to certificate validation because they perform the validations within the framework?

Comment: EnsureNoServicePointCertificate is a good way to clear the "cache". I use it for years in a system monitoring expiration date of SSL certificates of dozen of websites.

Comment: Ok but I didn't ask about clearing the cache, I asked about adding a certificate to the cache manually.