# how renegociate SSL-connection every time = different ssl-SessionID ( windows ,c#)

Tags: c#, ssl

How can i do in C#/Windows7 , that my app do not reuse existing SSL conenction. Actually when i make a get request with `HttpWebRequest` to a https page if there is an existing conenction then it use this connection (= same ssl-sessionid). I have done some test and windows 7 renegotiate the ssl connection after 2 minutes . But i will that it never reuse existing connection.

i have tried a lot of things:
keep-alive, ClientCacheTime (regedit), `ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive` ...

Thanks very much !

```
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout = 200;
           /* ServicePointManager.SetTcpKeepAlive(false,0,0);
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
            ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 1;*/
        //    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1;
            uri = "https://server.com/test.jsp";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
          WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0b; Windows NT 6.0)";
            request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";// content type

            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ConnectionGroupName = "dsd" + i;
           // request.ReadWriteTimeout = 2000;
           /* request.Timeout = 5000;
            request.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            request.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
            request.ConnectionGroupName = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(); */
           // X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("C:\\a.crt", "abcd");
           X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();
            request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
           /* request.PreAuthenticate = false;
            request.Pipelined = true;*/


            WebResponse rsp = request.GetResponse();
            string PageContent = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();


            textBox1.Text = PageContent;
            request.ServicePoint.CloseConnectionGroup("dsd" + i);
            request.Abort();

            request.ClientCertificates.Clear();
            rsp.GetResponseStream().Close();
            rsp.Close();
            request.Abort();
```

Comment: SslEmptyCache https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380388.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't provide much detail just some general pointers:

- set [`ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.dnsrefreshtimeout.aspx) to a very low value (default is 2 minutes = 120000 ms)
- set [`HttpWebRequest.ConnectionGroupName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y3d5dts.aspx) to a unique value on EVERY request
- call [`HttpWebRequest.ServicePoint.CloseConnectionGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.closeconnectiongroup.aspx) with that value AFTER EVERY request
- call [`HttpWebRequest.Abort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.abort.aspx) AFTER EVERY request

The above might work unreliably - depending on OS version and Framework version...

I am curious: achieving this means you have alot less performance... what is the goal ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
i have put some code and try what you say but it don't work :(.there is a windowsdll(SCHANNEL.dll) that handle the ssl connections is it a possibility to kill(unload) it and reload it every time ? i Use VS 2010 Express ,4.0.. it's for  testing purpose..

Comment: killing/unloading it would affect possibly the wohle system - so not really a good idea... perhaps it is better to have the SSL access in a seperate EXE and launch that EXE on every request, and kill it afterwards...

Comment: i have tried to kill and restart the exe but that also don't work i think , i must unload/reload the SCHANNEL.dll that handle SSL, if you have some code that would be nice or a external tool that can be used via cmd if it's too complicated in c#. thx

Comment: I don't think that doing so is going to help - SCHANNEL.dll is system-wide which means you could disturb the whole OS! IF you really must do what you want to do THEN use a third-party library which handles the whole SSL without using any OS API - this way you can achieve what you describe...

Comment: ok thanks i have find this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379810(VS.85).aspx  and the dwSessionLifespan is waht you need to change and i searching to do it...